# use xml schemas to create dynamic django models

Tags: xml, django, django-models

Is there any approach to use XML schemas to create tables. also I want to know whether I can use that approach with dynamic tables as well

updated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.Lahiruzz.com">

<xs:element name="note">
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
 <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
 <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
 <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
 <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample XML schema that you want to create a table from?

Comment: I updated my question. please  view.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at:
[generateDS -- Generate Data Structures from XML Schema](https://pypi.org/project/generateDS/)
it looks like what you requested

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I've updated the link, it now points to PyPI

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this a MSSQL and .NET related question

Have found this in Google

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/monicafrintu/archive/2007/06/12/how-to-create-tables-in-a-database-using-an-xsd-schema-and-sqlxmlbulkload.aspx

Hope it helps.

ADD:

Also found this http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html for python